# Exponential function: what have I done wrong?

Tags: python, function, numpy, matplotlib

I'm currently defining a function in python as:

```
def schechter_fit(stellarM, alpha=-1.35):
    schechter = (5.96E-11)*(10**((alpha+1)*((stellarM)-11.03)))*(2.7**((-10)**((stellarM)-11.03)))
    return schechter

schechter_range = numpy.linspace(10, 12, 10000)
```

And then plotting said function as:

```
ax.plot(schechter_range, schechter_fit(schechter_range), 'k')
```

This is the graphical output I am receiving is just a blank plot with no curve plotted.

Comment: ((x^2)*(2.718^-x))-10? If that's what you want i don't see how it's wrong. Not much to what you've done

Comment: @FirebladeDan Do you mean you need more info to see what's wrong? That's all the code that is required to make the plot shown...

Comment: I get a smooth curve when I plot it. Is that what you want?

Comment: Excellent. I should think so. Could you show me how you have plotted it please. Or even better add an answer with the picture of the plot.

Comment: Your plot is fine.  Your data's y range is so much bigger than your smooth plot, that the curve looks like a horizontal line.  If you don't plot the various Dn values, then you will see the original curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got a smooth plot (and looked up the [Schechter function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_function_%28astronomy%29); i hope that is what you want [i do not understand the `-10` though...])

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.axislines import SubplotZero

def schechter_fit(x, alpha=2):
    y = pow(x,alpha)*numpy.exp(-x)-10
    return y

schechter_range = numpy.linspace(10, 12, 10000)

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)
fig.add_subplot(ax)

ax.plot(schechter_range, schechter_fit(schechter_range), 'k')
```

[image: schechter_fit]

Comment: Could you add a picture of the plot please. I've just tried this and still the same as above...

Comment: looking at the y-range of your plot (and assuming what i did is correct) it looks like the curve is outside your plot region.